# How do I set the user status filter in ui-option sAjaxSource? (using laravel 5 + angularjs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel, datatable, laravel-5

I am calling  the users list from dashboard with filter the user status.

How do I change the url sAjaxSource from ui options.

```
<table   id="dataTable" ui-options="{
      sAjaxSource: 'api/users/',
      aoColumns: [
        { mData: 'first_name' },
        { mData: 'last_name' },
        { mData: 'email' },
        { mData: function(user_status){

        }
      ]
    }" >
```

Answer (score 0):

After spent some time on it I found solutions like this.

-1-----dashboard.blade.php----------

```
<a ui-sref="app.users({userstatus: 0})" >{{pending_users}} Inactive Users</a>
```

-2-----router.js----------

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    .state('app.users',{
    url:'/users/:userstatus',
    templateUrl: '/users',
    controller:'UserController as user'
    })  
</script>
```

-3-----users.js----------

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function UserController($scope, $stateParams) { 
        var userstatus = $stateParams.userstatus; 
        $scope.newurl='api/users/'+userstatus;
    }
</script>
```

-4-----users.blade.js----------

```
 <table   id="dataTable" ui-options="{
          sAjaxSource: '{{newurl}}',
        }" class="table table-striped b-t b-b">
 </table>
```

-5-----routes.php----------

```
<?php 
      Route::get('api/users/{userstatus?}', 'UsersController@usersList');
?>
```

-6-----UsersController.php----------

```
<?php

    public function usersList($userstatus=9)
    {
        if($userstatus=='9'){
            $users =User::where('user_type','=', 1)->get();
        }else{
            $users =User::where('user_type','=', 1)->where('user_status','=', $userstatus)->get();
        }

        return response()->json(['aaData' => $users]);
    }

?>
```